# Block incoming IPs in TidHTTPServer

Tags: indy, delphi-10.3-rio

I want to block certain client "OnConnect" to my Server, but I am not sure which event is best to use and how to find the remote IP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your app's code, using the `OnConnect` event is the simplest choice. You can get the client's IP from the `Binding.PeerIP` property of the provided `AContext` parameter, eg:

```
procedure TMyForm.IdHTTPServer1Connect(AContext: TIdContext);
begin
  if (AContext.Binding.PeerIP is blacklisted) then
    AContext.Connection.Disconnect; // or raise an Exception...
end;
```

However, a better choice is to put your server app behind a firewall that blocks connections by the desired IPs from reaching `TIdHTTPServer` in the first place.